# I2c Setup Issue

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, gpio, adafruit

I am trying to setup an Adafruit i2c temperature sensor in Python with a RaspberryPi4. The only example code for this sensor (SCD-40) sets up the i2c by importing board module:

```
import board
import adafruit_scd4x
i2c = board.I2C() # uses board.SCL and board.SDA
scd4x = adafruit_scd4x.SCD4X(i2c)
```

*** This works and runs fine on its own. My problem is that I also have 3 stepper motors which I'm controlling using RPI.GPIO:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
```

*** When I try bringing my i2c temperature sensor into the stepper motor Python code, I get an error telling me I cannot use board with RPi.GPIO
ERROR: (GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD) ValueError: A different mode has already been set!)

HOW CAN I SETUP AN I2C SENSOR WITHOUT USING THE import BOARD module? Is there a way to set it using RPi.GPIO

Comment: Are your GPIO lines the same pins as your I2C lines?

Comment: I added some tags that'll hopefully attract SMEs, which I'm not. Check out [How to ask a good question](/help/how-to-ask) for tips on how to use tags and also how to write a good title.

Comment: Tim Roberts yes they are.

Comment: Use @TimRoberts when you want to notify the user about comment reply.

Comment: Are you sure?  You can't use a pin for two different purposes.  Doesn't work.  If the pins are doing I2C, then they aren't available for GPIO.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need 'RPi.GPIO'? You can use 'board' with 'digitalio' to access to GPIOs.

```
import board
import digitalio
import busio

pin17 = digitalio.DigitalInOut(board.D17)
pin17.direction = digitalio.Direction.OUTPUT
pin17.pull = digitalio.Pull.DOWN

value = pin17.value
```

You can also use I2C with 'busio'

```
i2c = busio.I2C(board.SCL, board.SDA)
```

Read this [link](https://www.tomshardware.com/how-to/use-circuitpython-raspberry-pi) and this [link](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_Blinka/blob/main/examples/pi_digitalio.py).